# How do you remove links from sharepoint site with the XML Schema

Tags: xml, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-2007

I would like to know how you remove links from the sharepoint navigation usuing XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the ONET.XML file located at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\sts\xml in SharePoint 2010.

Refer to: [Removing items from the quick launch](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spucelik/2017/07/10/removing-items-from-the-quick-launch/)

Or we can hide the links using CSS style or JavaScript code.